# How to run parallel backup scripts by using parallel linux command

Tags: linux, shell

How to run parallel backup scripts by using [parallel linux command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel)

Better if shellscript for parallel uploads by using parallel command

Comment: what kind of backup? for which platform? Give us some information

Comment: What is the script backup name and which arguments does it receive? Do you have different files or directories you would like each script to take care?

Comment: It is backup of the local directory to remote gcp bucket using gsutil command and should be script

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a backup script called `backup_script.sh` and it receives one argument which is the directory or file to backup. Please note that the backup script must be capable of running in simultaneous (i.e: don't rely in non-dynamic temp files, etc)

You could easily use `parallel` like this:

```
# ls *.gz | parallel -j 3 ./backup_script.sh
Backed up file1.gz
Backed up file2.gz
Backed up file3.gz
Backed up file4.gz
```

What this does is simply to list all `*.gz` files in the current directory and run 3 simultaneous instances of the `backup_script.sh` script where each of them gets a different filename as an argument.

Please refer to [parallel man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

linux shell is perfectly capable to execute commands in parallel. For example:

```
sh command1.sh & sh command2.sh & sh command3.sh
```

these executes in parallel.

also say that you have bash file test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

./command1.sh &
./command2.sh &
./command3.sh &
```

when you execute `sh test.sh`, this also works parallel.

Comment: The op asked for a solution using parallel utility.